# How to generate points from an SVG

Tags: import

I have an SVG file with a 2D point-cloud, I want to convert each point in the svg into a point in Blender. Normally I would do it manually, but there are a lot of points and the they need to be placed very precisely. Is there a automatic way to place points in Blender?

Comment: Please add a sample to your question.

Comment: If the 2D point-cloud is a vector graphic (SVG), you can import SVG directly using **File > Import > Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG)**. We'll need more details on how the point-cloud is stored, otherwise it's a guessing game. :-)

Comment: Dave Jarvis already mentions the svg importer, and that might work for you. If not you could supply us with a snippet of the SVG (make a copy of the svg, delete a majority of the points, save and upload it somewhere or paste it as a gist to github for example:  https://gist.github.com/zeffii/d1fc3c9520300ca038cc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A working answer will depend heavily on the way your dots are written into the SVG file. Don't expect this code below to work. It might work, it might not. If you want a more specific snippet you need to provide a reduced version of the SVG in question -- it's easy to write specific code for specific files.

If the SVG is a bunch of *Circle Elements*, this is one way to extract the coordinates from the file.

This code assumes you have a file [like this](https://gist.github.com/zeffii/d1fc3c9520300ca038cc). Press the Raw button on that page to see what the underlying file looks like in text form. Essentially it contains an inner structure with the following lines. Each Line describes the center of a circle.

```
...
<circle id="path4142-96" cx="423.25" cy="500.82" r="5.8084"/>
<circle id="path4142-99" cx="540.43" cy="380.61" r="5.8084"/>
<circle id="path4142-23" cx="599.02" cy="179.59" r="5.8084"/>
...
```

This code detects the coordinates inside cx and cy and offers to scale them by some amount to prevent an otherwise massive mesh:

```
import bpy
import re


def svg_circles_to_vertices(filename, scale):
    verts = []
    add_vert = verts.append

    pattern = "cx=\"(.*)\" cy=\"(.*)\" "

    with open(filename) as f:
        for l in f:
            stripped = l.strip()
            if stripped.startswith('<circle'):
                m = re.search(pattern, stripped)
                if m:
                    x, y = m.group(1, 2)
                    x, y = float(x) * scale, -float(y) * scale
                    add_vert([x, y, 0])

    # print(verts)

    mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("mesh_name")
    mesh.from_pydata(verts, [], [])
    mesh.update()

    obj = bpy.data.objects.new("obj_name", mesh)

    scene = bpy.context.scene
    scene.objects.link(obj)


filename = "/home/zeffii/Desktop/drawing2.svg"
svg_circles_to_vertices(filename, 0.01)
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: This answer is going to be pretty useless if we are talking about an SVG file (as the edit implies). In that case the comments explain the method of importing an SVG into blender, which would solve the problem.
This answer only applies to raster images such as PNGs or JPGs. I'll keep it around only in case someone else wants to do this with a raster image and might bump into this answer.

If your 2D image is a simple black and white representation, this should do the trick:

1. Open your image in a UV/Image editor.
2. Open a text editor window and paste the script below there.
3. Update the image name in line 15.
4. Update the image resolution in line 18.
5. Press "Run Script".

Code:

```
import bpy
import numpy as np

def make_mesh( context, name, verts ):
    mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new( name = name )

    o = bpy.data.objects.new(name, mesh)
    o.location = (0,0,0) # place at object origin
    context.scene.objects.link( o )

    mesh.from_pydata( verts, [], [] )

    return o

img = bpy.data.images['figure_1.png']  # Update name to the right one in your scene

pixels = np.array( img.pixels[:] )
pixels = pixels.reshape( ( 1024, 1024 ) )  # Update resolution to the one in your image

verts = []
for i in range( pixels.shape[0] ):
    for j in range( pixels.shape[1] ):
        if pixels[i,j] == 0.0:
            verts.append( [ i, j, 0 ] )

o = make_mesh( bpy.context, 'PointCloud', verts )
```

[image: Screenshot]